# Printing stacktraces in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

All right, I'm kinda new to this JSP thing, so, please, don't crucify me if this is not the right way to do it.

I need to print the stackTrace in an error.jsp page, not only for the exception it recepted but also for all the chain of causes. So, I started by putting this in my web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Then, I've written this error.jsp file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>
<%@ page import="java.lang.Throwable" %>
<%@ page import="java.lang.StackTraceElement" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>An Error!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
            <h1>An Error!</h1>
            <table width="100%" border="1">
                <tr valign="top">
                    <td width="40%"><b>Error:</b></td>
                    <td>${pageContext.exception}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                    <td><b>URI:</b></td>
                    <td>${pageContext.errorData.requestURI}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                    <td><b>Status code:</b></td>
                    <td>${pageContext.errorData.statusCode}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                    <td><b>Stack trace:</b></td>
                    <td>
                        <c:forEach var="trace" 
                         items="${pageContext.exception.stackTrace}">
                            <p>${trace}</p>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            <% 
                Throwable cause =  pageContext.getException().getCause();
                while(cause != null) {
            %>

                <tr valign="top">
                    <td><b>Caused by:</b></td>
                    <td>
                        <% out.println(cause); %>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr valign="top">
                    <td><b>Stack trace:</b></td>
                    <td>
                        <%
                        StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = cause.getStackTrace();
                        for (int i = 0; i < stackTrace.length; i++) {
                            %> <p> <%
                            out.println(stackTrace[i]);
                            %> </p> <%
                        }
                        %>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            <%  cause = cause.getCause(); //Get next cause for the while loop
            }

            if (cause == null){
                %>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td><b>No further Cause</b></td>
                    </tr>
                <%         
            }

        %>

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's working correctly and doing the job quite well, but I recognize it's a heck of an ugly hack. Is there any way to do this more elegantly?

Thank you

Edited:

Forgot to mention the source of part of the code: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_exception_handling.htm

Answer (score 0):

Look at the section of the tutorial titled "Using JSTL tags for Error Page".  JSTL tags are one of several approaches for writing cleaner JSPs.  As you have noticed, the presence of any scriptlet (i.e. Java) code in a JSP is ugly.  JSTL provides clean syntax for referencing data in the various JSP scopes (page, request, session, app, ...) without having to write Java code.  I suggest you invest the time to familiarize yourself with this topic if you plan on doing JSP development.  It will be worth your while.